JWT Token Returns Empty String in gRPC Response
I'm building a microservices application using NestJS with gRPC for communication. I'm facing an issue where the JWT token is generated correctly and logged on the server-side, but it returns as an empty string when accessed via the client.
// GrpcAuthController.ts
@Controller()
export class GrpcAuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @GrpcMethod('AuthService', 'Login')
  async login(data: LoginRequest): Promise<LoginResponse> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(data.email, data.password);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials');
    }
    const loginResponse = await this.authService.login(user);
    console.log('Login Response:', loginResponse);
    return { access_token: loginResponse.access_token };
  }
}

// auth.interface.ts
export interface LoginResponse {
  access_token: string;
}

syntax = "proto3";

package auth;

service AuthService {
  rpc Login(LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse);
}

message LoginRequest {
  string email = 1;
  string password = 2;
}

message LoginResponse {
  string access_token = 1;
}


server log shows :
{ access_token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFhYWExQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IjY2YTc2ZjBkMDJhNzNmODMwYTAxNTA1ZCIsImlzVHdvRmFjdG9yQXV0aGVudGljYXRlZCI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTcyMjMxODgwOCwiZXhwIjoxNzIyMzIyNDA4fQ.LChjCnm04nznaPVJYwlYIEapMj6WirJczofrfLPmFjo' }
Client response shows:
{ "access_token": "" }
`enviroment :

"@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
"@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.11.1",
"node : v16.17.0"`

returning a token in client side
